# How to change desktop icon text background color?

Tags: themes, appearance

How do I change the background color of desktop text in 11.10. I used gnome color chooser in version 10.04, but it's not working in Ubuntu 11.10. Is there any way to solve this?

Also, by default there is no background just white fonts, which is a problem when I use light color wallpaper.

Comment: Interesting. I think that should be reported as a bug. That used to be a problem with lenses too. That was fixed.

Comment: Thanks... I tought that was because of change from gnome to unity. Anyway when I install Gnome color chooser there is the icon missing. Well with a fresh 11.10 install there are also other icons missing. But that I fixed with reinstalling the full theme again.

Comment: Unity doesn't replace Gnome. It is still Nautilus that draws the desktop.

Comment: I tryed to edit /usr/share/theme/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css but all I could do is to turn ON/OFF shadow of with text-shadow: none; (to turn it off). But when I add background-color: alpha (#464646); border-radius: 4; doesn't happen anything.

Comment: I haven't done any theming with Gnome 3, but have you tried color:#000000;?

Comment: Thank you! But I did tryed that too... I can change the color of the font, I can change shadow (on/off) but I just can't add background to the text. I even copy all the configuration from the part of selected icon definition, just to see what happen. But as I said nothing happen with the background. Seems like there is one more file where prevent the text to have a background.

Comment: Sorry, I misread you question. I understand. I don't think I've seen that before. It might not be possible, but don't give up! :)

Comment: I've tried to do the same thing. Basically I copied the block from .nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item:selected and used it to replace the default settings for .nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item, but nothing changes, even after I do killall nautilus and then re-open a Nautilus window. The background works for selected items, but not unselected items. I don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: Tried the same thing, no luck with background color on unselected desktop icons (Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work for you (I am using it in ubuntu 12.04), but you might try ubuntu-tweak :

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

when installed open it and go to:

> Tweaks>Theme

Then you can change 
Gtk theme

Icon theme

cursor theme

windows theme.

To whatever you would like.