# How to change icon background color on desktop?

Tags: themes, appearance

I'm trying to change the `background color` only referring to the icon text, as shown below.

[image]

I want to improve the display contrast of the icon text because I am using a `light background wallpaper` so I would like to know how to change the text color of the icons or keep the text color of the icons and change the `background color` of the icons.

I already tried using [ubuntu-tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92074/how-to-change-desktop-icon-text-background-color), however it only changed the display of the system icons, but it did not work.